# How should i create a new object with dynamic parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to specify the attributes only while they are filled but if they are `nil` or `{}` or `''` I shouldn't specify those parameters

the model Section is:

```
particular    :string           default("No"), not null
color         :enum             default("red"), not null
```

Only sometimes I need to create using the default if I don't specify the values.

```
Section.create(name: @name, particular: @particular, color: @color )
```

but i initialize @particular and @color with nil i am getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation:
       PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "particular"
```

I need to not specify in that case to get values by default

```
Section.create(name: @name )
```

Comment: You should be aware that `type` is the default type inheritance column in ActiveRecord and if you intend to use it for something else you need to set `self.inheritance_column = nil`. Not doing so will result in missing constant errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Hash#compact` to remove the keys with null values:

```
Section.create(
  { name: @name, particular: @particular, type: @type }.compact
)
```

Also I highly doubt you want to use an Enum type for this. In order to add new possible values or to delete an existing option you need to drop the type and re-add it.

The enum type should only really be considered if the possible options are finite and unchanging.